# Should "bring a plate" be taken literally?

Tags: idioms, australian-english

When someone is told to "bring a plate" to a picnic in Australia, does it literally mean just bring a plate? Or should they be bringing something else as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term *"bring a plate"* means that you bring some food along to the gathering to share with everyone. It doesn't have to be on a plate,  it can be any dish - and in general it's food that is ready to eat straight away.

Answer (score 8):

No.  You do not want to turn up with just a plate - ie a piece of crockery.

Bring a plate is to bring a plate of food that can be eaten from said plate.  This  can be either a sweet food such as pikelets or chocolate crackles; or savoury, such as triangle sandwiches, potato salad etc.

Less common is to bring a large dish, such as quiche or salad that needs a bowl rather than a plate, and even less common is to bring something that would serve as an entire course, ie roast lamb with vegetables.  Not entirely unknown, just less common.

As a meme, *bring a plate* arose as western social gatherings in Australia traditionally revolve around cartons of beer and meat being cooked on a barbecue with the occasional salad.  Bringing a plate added some involvement for the womenfolk, and the food kept the kids from going hungry - allowing the men longer time to keep drinking.   :-)

Comment: The same practices are followed in the US; the only difference is that we speak of bringing a *dish* rather than a plate. However, these days it's more usual to indicate that the dinner is *potluck* than to explictly demand that participants *bring* something. The exception is *BYOB*: "bring your own beer" (or "booze").

Comment: Dish is also used more broadly to mean some sort of prepared food item: "Her duck confit was a very well-prepared dish."

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of *synecdoche*, a figure of speech which uses part of a thing to mean the thing itself. In this case the word *plate* (or, in other locales, the *dish*) means *a plate of food*.

Synecdoche is used frequently in English. This is equally true of other languages. That can create a challenge when learning a new language, because it is not easy to imagine all the ways a word might stand for a part of something else.

“[Synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)” at *Wikipedia*
“[Synecdoche](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)” at *Simple Wikipedia*